# Drupal 9 contribution page url alias access denied

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

Drupal 9.5.10, CiviCRM 5.61.4.

Anonymous user can access
domain.tld/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=20

but not its alias domain.tld/subs created via domain.tld/admin/config/search/path
Drupal Watchdog gives the follow:

```
Path: /subs. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException:
in Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main() 
(line 86 of /var/www/html/drupal/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Controller/CivicrmController.php).
```

Doesn't look like civicrm permission issues since domain.tld/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=20 is accessible. What would it be?

Comment: If there's a stack trace that might help a bit but it's probably coming from CRM/Core/Invoke where it doesn't think it corresponds to an allowed menu item. Instead of an alias, could you try a redirect, so that drupal redirects it to the real url?

Comment: @Demerit  Unfortunately no backtrace has been given by Drupal, only watchdog message. Thank you for Redirect pointer, let's say this is a way to go for modern Drupal setups.